# Show that all order $n$ elements of $S_n$ are $n$-cycles if and only if $n=p^r$, $p$ prime

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

I'm looking to show that for any integer $n > 1$, every element of order $n$ in $S_n$ is an $n$-cycle
if and only if $n = p^r$
for some prime $p$ and some integer $r \geq 1$.

I am very new to group theory and I believe I need only surface level knowledge to prove this but I'm very stuck with how to start.

Comment: For $n=6$, can you find a order 6 element that isn't a 6-cycle? Does this suggest how to deal with the non-prime powers?

Comment: Why are you looking to show this in particular? (This question is phrased politely, but you are still essentially asking somebody else to solve the problem for you.)

Comment: "but I'm very stuck with how to start"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Suppose $n=p^r$. Let $\sigma$ be an element of order $n$. We can write $$\sigma=\alpha_1\dots\alpha_k$$
where $\alpha_i$'s are disjoint cycles.  Then note that $$p^r=|\sigma|=\text{lcm}(|\alpha_1|,\dots,|\alpha_k|).$$
Also note that $|\alpha_i|$ divides $p^r$. Use this information to show that one of the $\alpha_i$ must be $n$-cycle while the rest must be identity.

Conversely, suppose to the contrary that $n=p^rq$ where $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $q>1$. Find an element of order $n$ which is not an $n$-cycle. The suitable choice will be the product of a $p^r$-cycle and a $q$-cycle.

Comment: More than useful! Thank you for this

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.